# How accurate is Newtonian mechanics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, measurements

How accurate is (theoretical, i.e. the mathematical formulation basing on "formalised" physical constants, such as material density) Newtonian mechanics?

What does the accuracy depend on (material properties, environmental variations)?
And how (well) can these be "coupled" into calculations?

Comment: Depends entirely on what you are doing with it. As a theory of the solar system it's good to about ten digits, or so. As a theory of matter it's 100% wrong. It's not enough to know the workings of a theory, one also has to know its limitations.

Comment: @CuriousOne : Well it even fails in predicting Mercury's orbit...

Comment: @PrishChakraborty: It doesn't fail, it's just not as accurate as it is for Venus, Earth and the other planets. That's why I said that you have to know the limits in detail.

Comment: @CuriousOne : Touché

Comment: I have no idea how to make the question more specific.

Comment: @CuriousOne any chance you have references for this?

Answer (score -1):

The question is very vague and is perhaps best answered by reading about the failings of Classical Mechanics - for instance [here](http://physics.weber.edu/carroll/honors/failures.htm).

Newtonian Mechanics is accurate enough for [day-to-day calculations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_mechanics#Limits_of_validity).

Where Newtonian mechanics becomes inaccurate is in the very small, Quantum world or the very fast, where Special Relativity effects dominant. At very large scales, the generalised formulation of Spec. Rel. and applies it to newtonian gravitation i.e. [General Relativity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_mechanics#Limits_of_validity)

[image: Taken from Wikipedia link]
Generally, I would say if you have a mechanics problem in day-to-day life that cannot be calculated by Newtonian Mechanics, you will already know how to calculate it correctly. If you are unsure then Newtonian Mechanics is the one to use!

If you are interested in developing knowledge of advanced mechanics I would suggest following a course on Newtonian with Quantum Mechanics, Special Relativity and then General Relativity in that order.

Comment: Not entirely sure why I have been down voted as this is pretty much a paraphrasing of lecture notes and Wikipedia. Oh well...